# Kotlin + MVP - accidental override

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp

I'm using Kotlin & MVP together and stumbled on a little annoyance.

I'm getting an "accidental override" error (as you can tell from below). Are there any resolutions to this, besides changing either the member variable name or the getX() in the MainView interface.

From what i researched, there isn't a way to prevent kotlin from generating the getter for 'x'.

```
class MainActivity : Activity(), MainView {
    val x: String // Accidental override

    override fun getX(): String {
        return x
    }
}

interface MainView {
    fun getX(): String
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make your property `private` to prevent a getter being generated for it:

```
private val x: String = ""
```

Alternatively, you can make it a simple Java field instead of a property with the [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields) annotation:

```
@JvmField val x: String = ""
```

Comment: You may want to add that you can change the name of the getter with `@JvmName`